# Splitting XML feed into rows with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

New to stackoverflow and XML and XSLT.
I am receiving external XML feeds which cannot be edited and only transformed for output using XSLT. For example an XML feed could look like:

`<competition name="Comp1">`
  `<event name="test1">`

```
<competitor name="competitor1">
<competitor name="competitor2">
<competitor name="competitor3">

</event>
</competition>
```

and the standard xsl

```
<xsl:template match="event">
```

`<xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></xsl:attribute>`

```
</xsl:template>
```

will out put the following:

```
competitor1
competitor2
competitor3
```

Is there a way to print the name separately? i.e. competitor1 on its own and then where i needed i could print competitor2. is this possible?

My guess would be that i'd have to split up the competitor name but again I can't edit the XML file so not sure what approach to take.
And for more bad news, the system that the output is displayed on will not work with html.

```
Updated
```

The desired output would be something like:

```
competitor1              competitor2            competitor3
```

by doing this i can organize the output the way i need, ie. like above

Really appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Give an example of your wanted output.

Comment: And you wish it to print what? Each competitors name on a separate line? or?

Comment: Hi Kristofer, getting use to using stackoverflow, i updated the question. Usually i'll get an xml feed with a number of names ranging from 4 to 40, each time i get a new feed, a new layout or design for the output has to be made so ideally by breaking up the attributes individually i could display them within columns etc... Is this possible? Apologies for my severe novice-ness, I'm very new to xsl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example to guide you, depending on your output format you might wish to change the

```
<br/>
```

line breaks to something else, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017054/how-to-implement-carriage-return-in-xslt) post for examples.

Text output formatting(spaces/tabs/linebreaks etc) is always a bit complicated to get right so be prepared to spend some time with it.

Given the XML:

```
<competition name="Comp1">
  <event name="test1">
    <competitor name="competitor1"/>
    <competitor name="competitor2"/>
    <competitor name="competitor3"/>
  </event>
  <event name="test2">
    <competitor name="competitorX"/>
    <competitor name="competitorY"/>
    <competitor name="competitorZ"/>
  </event>
</competition>
```

With the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="competition/event">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    <br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="competitor">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will give you the following output:

```
test1
<br/>
competitor1 competitor2 competitor3
<br/>
test2
<br/>
competitorX competitorY competitorZ
<br/>
```

Comment: Cheers for the help @Kristofer, It certainly does require some amount of time but using the code above I should be able to get something done, appreciate it man!