# how to write code for new line in xslt

Tags: xslt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Producing a new line in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723226/producing-a-new-line-in-xslt)

hello can any one help me how to write code for getting newline ....

Comment: Do you want a newline in the XML/HTML file you are generating, or do you want something that displays as a new line in the browser? If the latter, you need to generate a `<br>` element.

Comment: Incidentally, you might like to know that I tend to assume people who are careless in writing English (for example, no capital letters) are also probably careless programmers. I might be wrong, but you should be aware of the impression you create.

Comment: What is your output format(e.g. XML, HTML, text)?  How are you verifying the newline(e.g. opening in a text editor or loading in a browser)?

Answer (score 1):

> bro i have tried every thing ....but
>   only newline was not getting for me
>   `&#xa;&#xD;&#10;` i have with this all –
>   praveen 4 hours ago

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="wrapLines">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:param name="pNumLines" select="10"/>

  <xsl:if test=
   "string-length($pText) and $pNumLines > 0">
   <xsl:variable name="vLine" select=
   "substring-before(concat($pText,'&#xA;'), '&#xA;')"/>
   <Line>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vLine"/>
   </Line>
   <xsl:call-template name="wrapLines">
    <xsl:with-param name="pNumLines" select="$pNumLines -1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
      "substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 line2
 line3
 line4
</t>
```

**it correctly finds all occurencies of an NL character and correctly splits the text into separate `<Line>` elements**:

```
<Line/>
<Line> line2</Line>
<Line> line3</Line>
<Line> line4</Line>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to output a new line or hard return? This will output a new line in the transformed file.

```
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
```

Comment: even in this case it will not return a new line. ... you should use ... <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>

Comment: This does output a newline.  I've used it when converting from XML to csv many times.