# Escaping new line in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my line of code

```
<xsl:template name="Reports">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/result/content/row"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

and this is the data in xml

```
<description>
 <![CDATA[ test test ]]>
</description>
```

tha data in xml is

test

test

How can i escape the new line in xslt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Producing a new line in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723226/producing-a-new-line-in-xslt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escapes are for

```
new line: &#10;
carriage return: &#13;
```

Comment: Is test the content of your row element?