# New line character within XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

```
          <td>
          <xsl:for-each select="participants/participant">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text> NEW LINE HERE   </xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
```

How can I get a new line where I have the text elements? I can have a space by having a space but I have tried everything to get return character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Producing a new line in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723226/producing-a-new-line-in-xslt)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051402/escaping-new-line-in-xslt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an actual newline in:

```
<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="participants/participant">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

Or, use an escape character such as `&#xa;`.

Comment: It's `&x0a;`, but yes.

Comment: While `xsl:text` is space-preserving, I would always go with `<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` as that's more resistant to any re-formatting of the XML file.  Your example in this answer, for instance, isn't just a newline but a newline followed by four spaces.

Comment: this doesn't work at all, just appears as a space still?

Comment: @AlanGordon This works perfectly. However, if you're viewing the result in a browser, any sequence of whitespace characters will be collapsed to a single space. Haven't you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are producing an HTML table, output a `<br/>` element (not text) when you want a line break.