# How to add a newline in XSLT output file

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to write a style sheet to generate code taking an XML file as input.
I tried a lot to insert a newline inside an `<xsl:text>` element by using `&#x0a;` or `&#x0a;&#x13` and also with

```
 <xsl:variable name='newline'><xsl:text>
 </xsl:text></xsl:variable>
```

but in output all of these things are adding a space character just like `&#160;`

The part of my code where I want to insert a newline is:

```
<xsl:variable name="StructType" select="diStructType"/>

 <line>
    <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($StructType, ';', ';&#xa;&#13;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;')"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </line>
```

Here `$StructType` is a string containing `;` in between. I am just trying to replace that `;` with `;+newline+(4*space)`.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of the XSLT? Text? HTML? XML?

Comment: You don't need the `&#13;`. This works fine for me using Saxon 9.3. What transform engine are you using?

Comment: Borodin its "xcodegen"

Comment: @tod - I assume you've seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723226/producing-a-new-line-in-xslt

Comment: @ABach I already seen the mentioned link as I mentioned in my question but its not working