# Adding a new line to the string

Tags: xpath, wso2, apache-axis, xpath-2.0, wso2-esb

hi am working with wso2esb4.9.0,

I have a service which generates email in that i have  property as mailbody  which am using to pass as body of the email.

```
<property name="mailbody"
                   expression="fn:concat('You have received a new Ticket',':','TicketID-',get-property('Ticketid'),', ','TicketDetails-',get-property('Details'))"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
```

when am passing this property in my service am getting a mail and mail body looks like as shown below.

```
You have received a new Ticket: TicketID-3021668982752443, TicketDetails-Test ticket details
```

I want to add a new line in the value so that the mail body can look like below instead of a single line.

```
You have received a new Ticket: 

TicketID-3021668982752443, 
TicketDetails-Test ticket details
```

Is there any Xpath function or way to add new line to my string value.

I have tried to include  \n and  in fn-concat of mailbody property but it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried using the encoded char for new line? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723226/producing-a-new-line-in-xslt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the XPath expression is inside of an XML document doing `expression="fn:concat('You have received a new Ticket',':&#10;','TicketID-',get-property('Ticketid'),', ','TicketDetails-',get-property('Details'))"` should suffice.

If you really use XPath 2.0 then you can also use `expression="fn:concat('You have received a new Ticket',':', codepoints-to-string(10),'TicketID-',get-property('Ticketid'),', ','TicketDetails-',get-property('Details'))"`.

Comment: Hi @Martin Honnen, I am using jDev 11g and BPEL1.0. Both solutions are not working for me. I am using inside assign activity. Below is my code ==> 
                                                                                                  
 concat('Dear XXXX,',codepoints-to-string(10),
'Your request ID XXXX has been approved. Kindly use below details for login. ',codepoints-to-string(10),
codepoints-to-string(10),codepoints-to-string(10),
'User ID: XXXX',codepoints-to-string(10),
'Password: XXXX')

Comment: Also I have tried ==> Also I tried ==> concat('Dear XXXX,',':&#10;',
'Your request ID XXXX has been approved. Kindly use below details for login. ',':&#10;',
':&#10;',':&#10;',
'User ID: XXXX',':&#10;',
'Password: XXXX')                                              but no luck!