# Wix and msbuild not producing newline character in some environments

Tags: xslt, msbuild, wix, vdproj

We have an installer from a Windows application. This is failing to build due to an XSLT issue.

The installer was originally a Visual Studio installer but when Microsoft removed this feature we converted it to Wix using **VDProj to WIX Converter**. This worked great.

The project file created by VDProj to WIX Converter is an MSBuild project file  which identifies the COM references as an XML file and uses XslTransformation (calling XslRegisterForCOM.xslt for those who know VDProj to WIX Converter) to output a plain text file with the filenames of the COM references (and subsequently resolves the paths).

However, in some environments this does not work because the intermediate text file does not have the correct line breaks (the XSLT uses &#13;&#10;), the references are all on the same line and cannot be resolved. At which point the build fails.

I've investigated the possibility that the newline character is incorrect and tried solutions from question such as:

[Producing a new line in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723226/producing-a-new-line-in-xslt)

The XSLT is definitely running and inserting something (if I replace the newline characters with plain text e.g. xxx this is outputted into the text file).

I've tried different version of Wix (in our working environment it is v3.8 but using this in other environments does not solve the problem). I also wondered if the file encoding is a problem.

Has anyone experienced this issue or has worked on **VDProj to WIX Converter** and recognises this as a known issue?

Comment: I resolved this by upgrading to the most recent version of VDProj to Wix, deleting the old Wix project and running VDProj to Wix again to create a new Wix project.