# how to change XML end of line character

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

when I generate xml output I can see the end of line character shows LF. bank requires it as CRLF.
need help how to fix this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R9An.png)

Comment: I'm not aware of any XML serializer that provides such an option. Logically, it's not needed, because if they're using a conformant XML parser then it's totally unnecessary. Sad thing is, even big outfits like banks are sometimes amazingly incompetent in their handling of XML. I think you're going to have to filter the output to add the CR characters, eg. using a custom OutputStream implementation.

Comment: Very harsh towards banks, @MichaelKay

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723226/producing-a-new-line-in-xslt) will help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any XML serializer that provides such an option. Logically, it's not needed, because if they're using a conformant XML parser then it's totally unnecessary. If you can't educate the bank to do things properly, I think you're going to have to filter the output to add the CR characters, eg. by using a custom `OutputStream` implementation